# How to call from Java Kotlin method which is named with escape characters?

Tags: java, escaping, kotlin

How this Kotlin function should be called from Java?

```
fun `some random function name`(){

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java provides no character escaping in identifiers. You can only do that using Java reflection:

<sub>Kotlin:</sub>

```
class MyClass {
    fun `some random function name`() { }
}
```

<sub>Java:</sub>

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.getClass().getMethod("some random function name").invoke(c);
```

<sup>Or cache the `Method` returned from the `getMethod()` call. Or use [method handles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html).</sup>

Comment: That's the answer that I needed :) Thanks:) +1